# ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 114: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to authenticate my user with the help of Helpers 
For this purpose i have make Helper folder in app directory. Add the following lines of code to the composer.json

```
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/UserHelper.php"
    ],
```

Make HelperServiceProvider.php in App\Provider directory, and use the following code in it.

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Providers;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
    /**
    * Bootstrap any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
    //
    }

    /**
    * Register any application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
    foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
       require_once($filename);
    }

    }
    }
```

after this  i have add alias in app.php as well as add provide like this

```
    //this is an alias   
   'UserHelper' => App\Helpers\UserHelper::class,
    //this is an provider 
    App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider::class,
```

My User model is

```
   <?php

   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class User extends Model {
   protected $table='users';
   protected $fillable =['username', 'password', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'groupname', 'about', 'image'];

   public static $login = [
   'username' => 'required|',
   'email' => 'required|',
   'password' => 'required'
   ];
   }
```

This my UserHelper

```
  <?php namespace App\Helpers;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
  class UserHelper {
   public static function processLogin($inputs){
    if(Auth::attempt($inputs)){
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
      }
     }
   }
```

Here is my Login Function

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\User;
    use Input;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator as Validator;

    use App\Helpers\UserHelper;


    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
    public function login() {

    $inputs = Input::except('_token');
        $validator = Validator::make($inputs, User::$login);

             if($validator->fails()){
                    print_r($validator->errors()->first());
        } else {
          $respones = \UserHelper::processLogin($inputs);

       if($respones){
            return 'loginView';
            } else {
            return 'not a user of our DB';
           } 
         }
       }
    }
```

I have also updated my composer and after i login to application following  error comes up , i am searching this for last 5 hour any help ?

Reards

Comment: checkout this..https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/fatalthrowableerror-while-attempting-to-authenticate

Comment: the website is down right now :(

Comment: no yaar working

Comment: class User extends Model dont extend the model here use authenticable when you are working with Auth

Comment: class User extends Authenticatable and use this line use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

Comment: thanks @sona it is working right now

Comment: post your answer in answer so that i can rate it up :P :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135855/discussion-between-sona-and-qadeer-sipra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In your code you are extending the  class User extends Model but when you are using auth functionality in laravel you need  to extend the auth rather than model..

Keep  Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User and extends the model like this...

class User extends Authenticatable{
 //code here 
}
```